# How to add hint to a factory method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm looking for a way to annotate return type of a factory function.

It returns random child of 'AlgorithmBase'.

```
class AlgorithmFactory:
    _algorithm_types = AlgorithmBase.__subclasses__()

    def select_random_algorithm(self) -> AlgorithmBase:
        # Select random algorithm
        algorithm_class = self._random_generator.choice(AlgorithmFactory._algorithm_types)
        algorithm = algorithm_class()
        return algorithm
```

I get error from mypy:

The error I'm getting is:

```
Cannot instantiate abstract class 'AlgorithmBase' with abstract attributes 'get_constraints' and 'satisfy_constraints'
```

There is no way to instantiate class 'AlgorithmBase' in this code, how to make mypy understand it?

I want to avoid specifying actual sub-classes with 'Union' in return type. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here wasn't return type, but '_algorithm_types'. mypy has no way to understand what type it is, so it assumed that it is like return type and got error.

The following code fix the issue:

```
_algorithm_types: List[Type[AlgorithmBase]] = AlgorithmBase.__subclasses__()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this should work, but it seems like one or more of your `AlgorithmBase` subclasses doesn't implement these two abstract methods.

Running MyPy for

```py
import abc

class AlgorithmBase(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_constraints(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def satisfy_constraints(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SomeAlgorithm(AlgorithmBase):
    pass


class AlgorithmFactory:
    def get(self) -> AlgorithmBase:
        algorithm = SomeAlgorithm()
        return algorithm
```

yields the same error you get, and it runs without any error once the methods are implemented.

```py
import abc

class AlgorithmBase(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_constraints(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def satisfy_constraints(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SomeAlgorithm(AlgorithmBase):
    def get_constraints(self):
        pass

    def satisfy_constraints(self):
        pass


class AlgorithmFactory:
    def get(self) -> AlgorithmBase:
        algorithm = SomeAlgorithm()
        return algorithm
```

Comment: This is correct. However error was on this line: `algorithm = algorithm_class()`. It selected random class out of `_algorithm_types` and gave error because it didn't know the type of `algorithm`. According to return type, it assumed that it might also be `AlgorithmBase` and gave error because this class is Abstract. Adding type on a variable solved the problem, which means that sometimes it is necessary to add hints to complex types, not just functions

Comment: In your case it 'knows' exactly the type of algorithm: `SomeAlgorithm` because you assign it directly, so no error here as you said

Comment: Also, if the issue was with an implementation of `AlgorithmBase`, that specific implementation would have been mentioned in the error message instead of the abstract class